# Filtering a URL and Trim it expected way

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I working to write a function in TypeScript/JS

https://sample.sharepoint.com/sites/Dev/_api/Web/lists/getbytitle('emp')/items`

https://sample.sharepoint.com/sites/Dev/Lists/emp/AllItems.aspx

From the above link, I want to form another URL reading values and passing to another.

Like I want to read first part https://sample.sharepoint.com/sites/Dev and then want to read emp and the value in this URL.

expected URL: https://sample.sharepoint.com/sites/Dev/_api/Web/lists/getbytitle('emp')/items

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @BenjaminToueg Not sure stuck with many tries. With index finding '/'

Comment: Can you help with that